# Authenticated from Facebook in MEAN

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

Is there any way to get authenticated from Facebook in MEAN **without** any 3rd party plugin like passport or auth0 or any other?

If yes then, please mention it.

Comment: Just curious, why would you want such a thing? Anyways, there is facebook JS SDK you can use.

Comment: use this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button integrate the button directly into your website and you dont have to install anything else , just few js lines